# I don't understand what the first line is defining or what the purpose of <Py_ssize_t>ceil is?

Tags: cython

```
cdef Py_ssize_t max_distance, offset

offset = <Py_ssize_t>ceil(sqrt(img.shape[0] * img.shape[0] +
                               img.shape[1] * img.shape[1]))
```

Can someone help me understand what the purpose of the the first line is when creating the variable after it? I dont understand what <Py_ssize_t> is because it seems like they do not assign anything to it. This is in Cython which I am brand new to and I only know python

Answer (score 2):

`<Py_ssize_t>` is a cast. Without context it's hard to know if it's necessary (but I suspect not). It casts whatever `ceil` returns to a C integer of type `Py_ssize_t` (a signed integer that is big enough to be used for sizes of Python containers). Documentation: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/userguide/language_basics.html#type-casting

The chances are it isn't necessary and would happen automatically with `offset = ceil`